# RNCamera Error:TypeError: CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined is not a function

Tags: android, react-native

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError:
>   CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined is not a
>   function. (In
>   'CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined()',
>   'CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined' is undefined)]

```
return (
  <View>
    <Text>Welcome to React Native QRScanner!</Text>

    <RNCamera
      ref={ref => {
        this.camera = ref;
      }}
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%'
      }}
      androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
        title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
        message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      }}
      onBarCodeRead={this.barcodeRecognized}
    >

    </RNCamera>
  </View>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Add using `captureAudio={false}` to bypass this error.

Answer (score 4):

1. Stop Developement server if running.
2. Remove `react-native-camera` with:

   ```
   yarn remove react-native-camera
   ```

   or:

   ```
   npm uninstall react-native-camera`
   ```
3. Add `react-native-camera` again with:

   ```
   yarn add react-native-camera
   ```

   or:

   ```
   npm i react-native-camera`
   ```
4. Run agian with `react-native run-android`

If you get an error like:

> Could not resolve project :react-native-camera

then you have to add line `missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'` in your `android/app/build.gradle` file under `defaultConfig`.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling by following the [official documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#requirements) resolved the problem for me (manual installation).

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to use : expo-camera

$ expo install expo-camera

More than : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/camera/