# Scan codes and error undefined is not an object

Tags: react-native

I would like to set up a scan for EAN13 codes, I am using the react-native-camera package but I ran into a **

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> '_reactNativeCamera.Camera.constants')

** and I will like your help to find out where is the error in my code.

If you can guide me, help me, that would be great, thank you very much.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Text,
View,
Alert,
TouchableOpacity,
Image
} from 'react-native';
import {Camera} from 'react-native-camera';
import styles from '../../../assets/styles'

export default class Ean13 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.handleTourch = this.handleTourch.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          torchOn: false
        }
      }
      onBarCodeRead = (e) => {
        Alert.alert("Barcode value is" + e.data, "Barcode type is" + e.type);
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
            style={styles.preview}
            torchMode={this.state.torchOn ? Camera.constants.TorchMode.on : Camera.constants.TorchMode.off}
            onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
            ref={cam => this.camera = cam}
            aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
            >
              <Text style={{
              backgroundColor: 'white'
              }}>BARCODE SCANNER</Text>
            </Camera>
            <View style={styles.bottomOverlay}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handleTourch(this.state.torchOn)}>
                <Image style={styles.cameraIcon}
                     source={this.state.torchOn === true ? require('../../../assets/images/flash.png') : require('../../../assets/images/no-flash.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        )
      }
handleTourch(value) {
  if (value === true) {
      this.setState({ torchOn: false });
    } else {
      this.setState({ torchOn: true });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used Camera

this should be RNCamera

```
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
```

And read the constants from

```
RNCamera.constants.TorchMode.on
```

Check the docs
https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md

Comment: Based on your answer, can i know the version that you have installed ?

Comment: @Kimako check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442458/rncamera-errortypeerror-cameramanager-checkifrecordaudiopermissionsaredefined

Comment: "react-native-camera": "^3.40.0", Ok I'll check your link, thank you

Comment: Well, I do not understand why but... i did "npm uninstall react-native-camera`" then "npm i react-native-camera" and it works... that's weird !!!

Comment: Maybe it had some cache, happens with libraries which has native code

Comment: Anyway, thanks again, you helped me a lot today or previous days !!! That's really nice of you !!!! :)