# TypeError: CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I'm trying to use the component `RNCamera` from 'react-native-camera' but after I accept permissions for my app to use my camera I get this error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined is not a function. (In 'CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined()', 'CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined' is undefined)]
* http://packager.ms-zi8.anonymous.reactnativeclient.exp.direct/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:423779:99 in requestPermissions$
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

The Component I'm rendering

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, ViewStyle, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import theme from '../Theme/theme';

// Components
import Box from './core/Box';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

type Props = {

}

const TakeMedia = ({}: Props) => {
  const cameraRef = useRef();

  // const takePicture = async () => {
  //   if (cameraRef.current) {
  //     const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
  //     const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
  //     console.log(data.uri);
  //   }
  // };

  return (
    <View style={ styles.container as ViewStyle }>
      <RNCamera
        // @ts-ignore
        ref={cameraRef}
        style={ styles.preview as ViewStyle }
        type={ RNCamera.Constants.Type.back }
        flashMode={ RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on }
        androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
          title: 'Permission to use camera',
          message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
          buttonPositive: 'Ok',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        }}
      />
      <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={ styles.capture as ViewStyle }>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
}

export default TakeMedia;
```

I have already tried this solution [RNCamera Error:TypeError: CameraManager.checkIfRecordAudioPermissionsAreDefined is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442458/rncamera-errortypeerror-cameramanager-checkifrecordaudiopermissionsaredefined)

Answer (score 0):

Add `captureAudio={false}` to bypass this error.

```
<RNCamera
    ...
    captureAudio={false}
>
</RNCamera>
```